# Объединить две функции sumif()

Tags: excel

Есть две функции:

```
=sumif(range;criteria_1;[sum_range])
=sumif(range;criteria_2;[sum_range])
```

где `criteria_*` — некое слово.
Как их объединить (красивее, чем `=sumif(...)+sumif(...)`)?

Вариант `=sumif(range;"*criteria_1*"&"*criteria_2*";[sum_range])` возвращает ошибку.
Решение через `sumifs()` возвращает `0`, возможно из-за того, что `range` одинаковые.
Вариант `sumifs(sum_range;criteria_range;{criteria_1;criteria2})` суммирует только для `criteria_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вариант =sumif(range;"*criteria_1*"&"*criteria_2*";[sum_range]) возвращает ошибку.

Синтаксис правильный и ошибки не будет - формула покажет 0 (ноль), если в диапазоне нет текста, содержащего указанные два слова, ведь критерий - сцепленный текст.

Применяя массив констант (значения в фигурных скобках), Вы были близки к правильному ответу.

С таким массивом *СУММЕСЛИ(sumif)* работает, но и результат работы функции - тоже массив (в данном случае из двух значений). Остались просуммировать их:

```
=sum(sumif(range;{"criteria_1";"criteria_2"};[sum_range]))
```

Это для варианта, когда нужно получить сумму отдельных значений,  полученных по разным критериям (объединить по условию *ИЛИ*).

Если же проверка в разных диапазонах и условие общее (объединить по условию *И*), то *sumif* не справится, нужно вызывать младшую сестренку - *СУММЕСЛИМН* (*sumifs*)

```
=sumifs(sum_range;range1;"criteria_1";range2;"criteria_2"})
```

Можно проверить общее условие (объединить по условию *И*) для одного диапазона, если критерии не противоречат друг другу. Пример: суммировать значения *sum_range*, если значение в *range* не находится в диапазоне 2-15:

```
=sumifs(sum_range;range;"<2";range2;">15"})
```

или со ссылками на ячейки:

```
=sumifs(sum_range;range;"<"&A1;range2;">"&A2})
```

Еще вариант - поиск вхождения критериев в значениях одного диапазона (по условию *И*)

```
=sumifs(sum_range;range;"*criteria_1*";range;"*criteria_2*"})
```

знак подмены * - любое количество символов

Если порядок следования критериев известен, достаточно *sumif*:

```
=sumif(range;"*criteria_1*criteria_2*";[sum_range]))
```

Comment: странно, но с `sumifs` не работает. наверное `range` должны быть разные http://imgur.com/SkSMMGL http://imgur.com/IGE32Gl - второй вариант тоже попробовал

Comment: Да, ведь не может значение одновременно равняться и одному, у другому. Поправил в ответе.